# Interactive map for linguistic purposes

Tags: web-mapping, database, references

I would like to learn how to do dynamic/interactive maps for users interested in linguistic issues. In short, the idea is that a user could choose for instance between two syntactic constructions (Put on your coat vs Put your coat on) and the map would show the geographic distribution of the option selected by the user according to a database.

I am new to the GIS world. I just worked a bit with QGIS to do some basic maps with my own data, but I do not know how to do interactive web-based maps. So by now I just would like to get basic information in order to understand well the necessary steps I need to follow.

Can you siggest an introductory book, resource, software, etc?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-mapping+references may provide a starting point.